# Build count columns by each occurring value of groups

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame with multiple entries per day, indexed by a datetime. Now I want to group all the rows by day and create new columns with the counts of each occurring value for that day.

Take a look at this example:

```
                           value
startDate
2017-06-08 16:00:00+01:00  True
2017-06-08 17:00:00+01:00  True
2017-06-08 18:00:00+01:00  True
2017-06-08 19:00:00+01:00  True
2017-06-08 20:00:00+01:00  True
...                        ...
2019-12-02 19:00:00+01:00  True
2019-12-02 20:00:00+01:00  False
2019-12-02 21:00:00+01:00  True
2019-12-02 22:00:00+01:00  True
```

I'd like to transform the data to this result:

```
            True  False
date
2017-06-08  5     0
...         ...   ...
2019-12-02  3     1
```

I figured out that I can group by day like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data.csv', parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])

by_day = df.groupby(df.index.date)
```

Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how go on from here and create the "count columns" and all the resources I found online only counted all elements in each group. Any hint in the right direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df  = pandas.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-02'],
    'value': [True, False, False, True, False]
})
```

You can use the `value_counts()` function of the SeriesGroupBy object:

The [documentation of that particular function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) is a little thin, but you can refer to the [`pandas.Series.value_counts()` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), which covers the parameters.

```
df.groupby('date')['value'].value_counts().unstack(level='value', fill_value=0)

# Result:
value       False  True 
date                    
2019-01-01      2      1
2019-01-02      1      1
```